# Share data between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, storyboard, share, viewcontroller

I'm building a multi view app for iPad. For now, I have 3 `ViewControllers` on a `SplitViewController Application`. How do I send data that was inserted on `ViewController 1` and `View Controller 2` to `ViewController 3`?
Here is an image from my storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new class Singleton with parent NSObject

```
@interface Singleton : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringParams1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringParams1;

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

Singleton.m:

```
@implementation STGameHelper

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

So in the view controller 1 and 2 just access this singleton:

```
Singleton *s = [Singleton sharedInstance];

s.stringParams1 = textField1.text;
s.stringParams2 = textField12.text;
```

In the view controller 3 you will have the same instance of singleton. Access it in viewDidLoad for example:

```
Singleton *s = [Singleton sharedInstance];

textField1On3rdViewcontroller.text = s.stringParams1;
textField2On3rdViewcontroller.text = s.stringParams2;
```

Read more about singleton here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

As you are beginner I recommend you using singleton instead of core data right now, but if you need to store the data after they were entered I will suggest you read some tutorial how to work with core data because it is very powerful thing and it will make you life easiest. But for now it's enough to have singleton if you need to store data after app will be closed for example.

Comment: I am beginner on programming. Then, I didn't understand very well what you said. Is there any documentation or exemple? thanks

Comment: I will test your code @Matrosov, then I will let you know if it worked. I am watching on Itunes U the Standford classes, that's why i mentioned Core Data. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Feel free to ask me =) So honestly it depends on tasks. If you need to pass data you can create singleton or pass all parameters through the all components using properties (bad way), but if you need store data - then core data it is what you need. But only in case if the task is required store data in database, if it is dynamic data you don't need to use any database wrappers like core data and etc.

Comment: PERFECT. My problem is SOLVED. Thanks @Matrosov. Next step, learn protocols and delegates.

Answer (score 2):

Consider you want to send string data to ViewController2,ViewController3 from ViewController1.

Make property of the string variable in ViewController2 and ViewController3.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *str;
```

And while pushing the ViewController2 and ViewController3:

```
  ViewController2 *viewController = [ViewController2 alloc]init];
  viewController2.str = @"Some text";
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

And you have the data send from ViewController1 in ViewController2.

Comment: But I am not using navigation controller. So... It doesn't help me. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep a reference to the data and either pass it between view controllers, or retrieve it from somewhere. It can be from a local database, from an in-memory object in a singleton instance or whatever.

Maybe in your use case, the view controller that triggers the segues (the one with a lot of buttons) can hold an object containing the data, and pass it to the view controllers 1, 2 and 3 when the are about to appear.

Comment: Well... How do I do that? I don't have any idea. It is using Core Data?

Comment: No, don't use core data just for that. Was just a comment to let you know that data can come from many sources. In your case, probably it's better to declare a @property in each view controller, and pass that property around.

Comment: So,  I created a @property on ViewController 1. Then I alloc and init this viewcontroller on viewcontroller 3 and get the data? thanks

Comment: No, then also add a @property on viewController3. Then when you present viewController3, set the property with the same object you have in view controller 1 (or whichever view controller is presenting view controller 3)

Comment: Let's see... For Exemple... On ViewController1, I have @property NSArray *array1. Then some code to store objects on it. Now, ViewController3, has a property NSArray *array2. Then, somewhere in my code I do: viewController1 *vc1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init]; self.array2 = vc1.array1. That's right?

Comment: sorry I have edit your post instead of mine. I don't know if you minus me or not, but I think singletons it is a good idea to have all data passed to another component like view controller.